# Combinatorics and selections

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

An ice-cream parlor sells 10 different flavors of ice-cream.

(a) A medium bowl has 3 scoops. How many distinct bowls are possible?

**My answer: $\frac{12!}{9!\times3!} = 220 $**

(b) A medium cone has 3 scoops. How many distinct cones are possible, and how is this different to part (a)?

**My answer: $\frac{12!}{9!}-100 = 1220$, the difference being that the order of the scoops now matters (apart from when 3 scoops of the same flavor are chosen)**

I'm not sure if these are correct so if someone could check these I'd be grateful.

Comment: Where does the $12$ come from?  Did you mean to say there were $12$ different flavors?

Comment: Note:  even if you did mean $12$ flavors, you've only counted the "three flavor" bowls.  You also need to consider the "two flavor" and "one flavor" sort.

Comment: I used the combinations with repetition formula. This should take into account what you said about taking a certain flavor more than once. It ends up with 12 in the formula

Comment: Ah, I see.  Fair enough!  Certainly, I agree that $220$ is the correct answer.

Comment: For part $b$, though, I think it's clearer to separate the cases.  For the $\binom {10}3=120$ distinct cases we multiply by $6$ to get all permutations.  For the $10\times 9=90$ two flavor cases we multiply by $3$.  And for the one flavor cases we still just have the $10$.  Hence $120\times6+90\times 3+10=1000$.

Answer (score 2):

For $b$, since the order matters, you just have $10$ choices at each stage for a total of $10^3$.  It certainly cannot be greater.